# Subtitle not displaying for videojs player with Vimeo embed video

Tags: html5-video, video.js, vimeo, webvtt

The text tracks I am adding to the videojs player are not being displayed in the player.

I am embedding a vimeo video to a videojs player using the library - https://github.com/videojs/videojs-vimeo

I could add `remoteTextTrack` and I could see the cues being added to the Text track in the console, but for all the cues the `displayState` is showing as `undefined`, which is the reason the captions are not rendering. Couldn't understand why this is happening.

This is how I am adding :

```
playerRef.remoteTextTracks().tracks_.forEach(remoteTrack => {
  const currCue = new VTTCue(stTime, enTime, "HARI SHANKAR");
  remoteTrack.addCue(currCue);
});
```

This is the response I am getting in the console for the 
VTTCue:

```
0: VTTCue
addEventListener: ƒ addEventListener()
align: "middle"
dispatchEvent: ƒ dispatchEvent()
displayState: undefined
endTime: 5
hasBeenReset: false
id: ""
line: "auto"
lineAlign: "start"
onenter: null
onexit: null
originalCue_: VTTCue {vertical: "", snapToLines: true, line: "auto", position: "auto", size: 100, …}
pauseOnExit: false
position: 50
positionAlign: "middle"
region: null
removeEventListener: ƒ removeEventListener()
size: 50
snapToLines: true
startTime: 0
text: "HARI SHANKAR"
track: null
vertical: ""
```

I have also tried by adding VTT file using `<track>` as :

```
<video ref={node => (this.videoNode = node)} className="video-js">
  <track kind="captions" src="/sample.vtt" srcLang="en-US"label="English" />
</video>
```

even this way I couldn't get any captions. Can someone help ?

Answer (score 1):

Is this issue still occurring for you? Vimeo recently pushed a fix to address an issue with caption and subtitle files (around 2:53pm ET)

Comment: Yes it's happening for me. Can you share any link please